# Retrieving values for checkbox with sqlreader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to retrieve and populate the values for some checkboxes. I have no problem doing this with textboxes, but I can't seem to get it to work with checkboxes.

This is how I fill textboxes:

```
supplier_name.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
```

Is there something similar I can use to populate a checkbox? The data is being stored as True/False in the database.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
supplier_nonprofit.Checked = rdr[14].ToString();
```

Comment: `supplier_nonprofit.Checked = (bool)rdr[14];` try that

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this but it throws an invalid cast exception. However, the following works fine: `System.Boolean.Parse(rdr[14].ToString());` I probably just needed to add a `.ToString()` to the end of your code.

Comment: or `(bool)rdr[14].ToString()` works as well no need to qualify System.Boolean you can do `Boolean.Parse(rdr[14].ToString()` you all ready have by default at the top of your class `using System`

Comment: no problem..  just wanna save you typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a string in the database then:

```
supplier_nonprofit.Checked = System.Boolean.Parse(rdr[14].ToString());
```

If it's a bit or Boolean type then:

```
supplier_nonprofit.Checked = (System.Boolean)rdr[14];
```

Comment: you do not need to qualify the second example using `(System.Boolean)` just casting as `(bool)rdr[14];` will do the same thing btw

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The data is being stored as a string. Your first example works perfect! Thanks again!